# Cordova Android Referrer

Tags: javascript, android, git, cordova

I want to ask you guys some question, its about cordova and android referrer, by using the referrer, we can get the value from google play like this

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.maingames.android.CGID&referral=question

we can get the referral that referral=question

I used this plugin to use referrer function

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-android-referrer

unfortunately, when i try to use

```
cordova plugins add https://github.com/8zrealestate/android-referrer-plugin
```

its show up like this

> Error: Failed to fetch plugin
>   LINK via registry.
>   Probably this is either a connection problem, or plugin spec is
>   incorrect. Check your connection and plugin name/version/URL. Error:
>   cmd: Command failed with exit code 4294963228 Error output: npm WARN
>
> ### addRemoteGit Error: Command failed: git -c core.longpaths=true config
>
> -get remote.origin.url npm WARN addRemoteGit npm WARN addRemoteGit     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:206:12) npm WARN
>   addRemoteGit     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13) npm WARN addRemoteGit
>   at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7) npm WARN addRemoteGit     at
>   maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:877:16) npm WARN addRemoteGit 
>   at Socket. (internal/child_process.js:334:1 1) npm WARN
>   addRemoteGit     at emitOne (events.js:96:13) npm WARN addRemoteGit 
>   at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7) npm WARN addRemoteGit     at
>   Pipe._handle.close [as _onclose] (net.js:498:12) npm WARN addRemoteGit
>   git+htttps://github.com/8zrealestate/android-referrer-plug in.git
>   resetting remote
>   C:\Users\ideapad\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_git-remotes\
>   git-htttps-github-com-8zrealestate-android-referrer-plugin-git-e8aa7510
>   because o f error: { Error: Command failed: git -c core.longpaths=true
>   config --get remote .origin.url npm WARN addRemoteGit npm WARN
>   addRemoteGit     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:206:12)
>   npm WARN addRemoteGit     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13) npm WARN
>   addRemoteGit     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7) npm WARN
>   addRemoteGit     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:877:16) npm
>   WARN addRemoteGit     at Socket.
>   (internal/child_process.js:334:1 1) npm WARN addRemoteGit     at
>   emitOne (events.js:96:13) npm WARN addRemoteGit  at Socket.emit
>   (events.js:188:7) npm WARN addRemoteGit     at Pipe._handle.close [as
>   _onclose] (net.js:498:12) npm WARN addRemoteGit   killed: false, npm WARN addRemoteGit   code: 1, npm WARN addRemoteGit   signal: null, npm
>   WARN addRemoteGit   cmd: 'git
>   -c core.longpaths=true config --get remote.ori gin.url' } npm ERR! addLocal Could not install
>   C:\Users\ideapad\AppData\Local\Temp\npm-6372
>   -d9aee34f\git-cache-7c50b9fc\3eb612d3fbe61a5291f69d47dc97faee4418aa14 npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.2.9200 npm ERR! argv "C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\
>   node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "install"
>   "htttps://github.com/8zrealestate/a ndroid-referrer-plugin" "--save"
>   npm ERR! node v6.9.2 npm ERR! npm  v3.10.9 npm ERR! code EISDIR npm
>   ERR! errno -4068 npm ERR! syscall read
>
> npm ERR! eisdir EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read npm
>   ERR! eisdir This is most likely not a problem with npm itself npm ERR!
>   eisdir and is related to npm not being able to find a package.json in
>   npm ERR! eisdir a package you are trying to install.
>
> npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
>   npm ERR!     I:\cordova\notif2\node_modules\npm-debug.log

I've read some topic that said my git got problem, but I dont think so because I can clone this project, but when I try to add it locally, it wont work too..

Is there any alternative ? thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Install [referrer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-android-referrer-plugin) plugin using following command, it works

```
cordova plugins add cordova-android-referrer-plugin
```